# AJAX to retrieve and store object in a variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two files. One is `index.php` where the user clicks and invokes an AJAX request. The second one is `process.php` whic sends back data back to `index.php`.

```
function AjaxResponse() {
    var myData = 'connect=1'; 
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process_facebook.php",
        dataType: "text",
        data: myData,
        success: function(response){
            $result = response;
            window.location.replace("http://myurl.com");
        }
```

the $result doesn't here. I can do like this $('#something').html(response); but can't store the value returned in a variable.

Comment: You are using php like variables. You have to use "var result = response;"

Comment: @veelen - this is an answer not a comment :)

Comment: `process.php !== process_facebook.php`  see if this is the case.

Comment: @veelen declare var result then can be access in php?

Comment: then where do you want to use `$result`? it seems no issues whatsoever. try `alert($result);`

Comment: $result in index.php, but I use redirect in the ajax callback.. and in the index.php, it check whether the user's session is set.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of hard to tell what you would like here. But I'm going to guess that you want to store the result of the ajax call into a variable in php. So I'll remind you the order in which things proceed for a server/client web interaction.

Server processing ==> client side processing ==> repeat.

The only real way to store that value in a variable after receiving the data from your ajax request would be to submit a form and have your data serialized into JSON or xml and then parse it.

Alternatively, your `process_facebook.php` file could insert your data into a database and you could return a key to your callback, and either create a cookie on the users browser of that key, or have the browser pass that key as a get variable to your index.php (sanitize it so that a malicious user can't just go entering whatever they want), and then do what you want with that information.

To clarify, the session is not stored on the browser, it is stored on the server, you cannot set any session variables on the browser unless you did it in an ajax call to the server.

Comment: how about set an array into a session in the process_facebook.php and use it in my index.my?